# Observables combine with combineLatest Observables which are generated in a for loop

Tags: loops, angular2-observables, combinelatest

I am trying to combine observables, where each observables gets the input in a for loop. My problem is, that I would know how to do it **without** the `for loop`, if I know the array the `for loop` would loop over in advance -> I would just put everything inside the `combineLatest`.

Does anyone know how I would do this, if I do not know the size of `sections`?

Many thanks in advance!

```
getArticleSectionsContent(pageId: string): Observable<any> {
 return this.getArticleSections(pageId).pipe(
  switchMap(sections => {
    return combineLatest([
      this.getArticleSectionContent(pageId, sections[0].index),
      this.getArticleSectionContent(pageId, sections[1].index),
      this.getArticleSectionContent(pageId, sections[2].index),
    ]).pipe(
      map(([a, b, c]) => {
        return { a, b, c };
      })
    );
  })
 );
}
```

Comment: Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the size of sections, loop through your array with the map operator to convert it into an array of observables, like this:

```
getArticleSectionsContent(pageId: string): Observable<any> {
 return this.getArticleSections(pageId).pipe(
  switchMap(sections => {
    const articleSectionContentObsArray = sections.map(section => {
        return this.getArticleSectionContent(pageId, section.index);
    });
    return combineLatest(articleSectionContentObsArray);
  })
 );
}
```